# Does Firebase will act as server? Where to write common code?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new to the android development. I want to create android app to do some calculation. That calculation will be generic and common to all the user. So instead of writing the code in the app. I plan to write those business function in server side. Then I will collect the request from user and do the calculation in server side and send the result to the client again. 
    Nowadays Fire-base is popular for android development instead of server and database.

Question Is:

1. Is it possible with the fire-base? Does Cloud function is helpful for this? Please let me know the possible way
2. Can Cloud function written in java?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it'll be possible. It is a pretty simple task though and will require some work to set it up first. If you do it in firebase, you can first push your data to the firebase database, add a listener to it with cloud function's [db trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) who calculate the result and store it in the db. You can then load that result from the db.
   You should be aware that cloud functions are not included in the free plan.
2. No, it requires you to use javascript / node.js. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started